# for-each in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to loop all the elements inside my root tag like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<root>
<mijnFamilyPack>
    <rt>id123</rt>
    <rt>id345</rt>
    <rt>id084</rt>
    <INPORTING>NO</INPORTING>
    <id>345</id>
</mijnFamilyPack>
</root>
```

I have wrote for-each to get all "rt" element values. But i can the first cvalue alone.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/mijnFamilyPack/">
<xsl:value-of select="rt"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

How do I get 'rt' values alone?

Comment: one little bit changes in my xml code.

Comment: try to always post complete source xml and complete xsl code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Oded said you should use a template to match the `rt` elements. `For-each` should not be used here (see also answers in this thread: [For loops vs. apply-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342902/for-loops-vs-apply-templates))

If you apply this XSLT to your source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <list>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//rt"/>
    </list>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rt">
    <rt>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </rt>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you get the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
<rt>id123</rt>
<rt>id345</rt>
<rt>id084</rt>
</list>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have only one instance of node `mijnFamilyPack`, hence `<xsl:for-each select="/root/mijnFamilyPack/">` is looping a single time and you are printing value of first `rt` node.

You may want to put `rt` node also in your `for-each` and print the value of current node as below:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="/root/mijnFamilyPack/rt">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

If you think there could be multiple nodes of `mijnFamilyPack` then use nested loop, first to iterate `mijnFamilyPack` and then second to iterate `rt` inside `mijnFamilyPack` nodes.

```
 <xsl:for-each select="/root/mijnFamilyPack/">
    <xsl:for-each select="rt">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting the `mijnFamilyPack` node, not the set of `rt` nodes:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/mijnFamilyPack/rt">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Consider using an actual template instead of `for-each`, however:

```
<xsl:template match="/root/mijnFamilyPack/rt">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```