# No XSL transformation of a maximo response

Tags: xml, xslt, maximo

This is my response message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
    <QueryMXCPISResponse baseLanguage="EN"
        creationDateTime="2014-11-25T11:56:09+01:00"
        maximoVersion="7 5 20130829-1209 V7510--1"
        messageID="1416912970550686680" rsCount="3" rsStart="0"
        rsTotal="3" transLanguage="EN"
        xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <MXCPISSet>
            <CPIS>
                <AK>D</AK>
                <CPISID>630124</CPISID>
                <ORGID>01</ORGID>
                <S1>0</S1>
                <S2>0</S2>
                <S3>0</S3>
                <S4>0</S4>
                <S5>0</S5>
                <S6>1</S6>
                <SHIFT>3</SHIFT>
                <SHIFTDATE>2014-09-30T00:00:00+02:00</SHIFTDATE>
                <SITEID>0030</SITEID>
                <STATUS>NEW</STATUS>
                <TEAM>C</TEAM>
                <WP>LC11</WP>
                <ASSET>
                    <ASSETNUM>LC11</ASSETNUM>
                    <LOCATION>FACILITY-1</LOCATION>
                    <SITEID>0030</SITEID>
                </ASSET>
            </CPIS>
            <CPIS>
                <AK>D</AK>
                <CPISID>630121</CPISID>
                <ORGID>01</ORGID>
                <S1>0</S1>
                <S2>0</S2>
                <S3>1</S3>
                <S4>0</S4>
                <S5>0</S5>
                <S6>1</S6>
                <SHIFT>1</SHIFT>
                <SHIFTDATE>2014-09-30T00:00:00+02:00</SHIFTDATE>
                <SITEID>0030</SITEID>
                <STATUS>CHECKED</STATUS>
                <TEAM>B</TEAM>
                <WP>LC11</WP>
                <ASSET>
                    <ASSETNUM>LC11</ASSETNUM>
                    <LOCATION>FACILITY-1</LOCATION>
                    <SITEID>0030</SITEID>
                </ASSET>
            </CPIS>
            <CPIS>
                <AK>D</AK>
                <CPISID>630122</CPISID>
                <ORGID>01</ORGID>
                <S1>1</S1>
                <S2>1</S2>
                <S3>0</S3>
                <S4>0</S4>
                <S5>0</S5>
                <S6>1</S6>
                <SHIFT>2</SHIFT>
                <SHIFTDATE>2014-09-30T00:00:00+02:00</SHIFTDATE>
                <SITEID>0030</SITEID>
                <STATUS>APPLIED</STATUS>
                <TEAM>B</TEAM>
                <WP>LC11</WP>
                <ASSET>
                    <ASSETNUM>LC11</ASSETNUM>
                    <LOCATION>FACILITY-1</LOCATION>
                    <SITEID>0030</SITEID>
                </ASSET>
            </CPIS>
        </MXCPISSet>
    </QueryMXCPISResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

And this my xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="MXCPISSet">
 <html>
  <body>

   <table>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <th>WP</th>
      <th>Site</th>
      <th>Shift</th>
     </tr>

     <xsl:for-each select="CPIS">
     <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="WP"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="ASSET/SITEID"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="SHIFT"/></td>
     </tr>
     </xsl:for-each>

    </tbody>
   </table>


  </body>
 </html>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the result:

```
D 630124 01 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 2014-09-30T00:00:00+02:00 0030 NEW C LC11 LC11 FACILITY-1 0030 D 630121 01 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 2014-09-30T00:00:00+02:00 0030 CHECKED B LC11 LC11 FACILITY-1 0030 D 630122 01 1 1 0 0 0 1 2 2014-09-30T00:00:00+02:00 0030 APPLIED B LC11 LC11 FACILITY-1 0030
```

If I delete xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" from response message i get the correct output

```
WP      Site    Shift
LC11    0030    3
LC11    0030    1
LC11    0030    2
```

What is wrong in my XSL file that I don't get the HTML output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements `QueryMXCPISResponse`, `MXCPISSet`, etc are in the namespace `xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo"`. Without the namespace, the processor doesn't match any elements, and instead of applying your stylesheet, the [default processing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360017/why-does-xslt-output-all-text-by-default) are applied. You'll need to accommodate this namespace in your template, as follows (note the `xmlns` and alias, `m` for maximo):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0"
                xmlns:m="http://www.ibm.com/maximo"
                xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                exclude-result-prefixes="soapenv m">

  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" >
    <xsl:apply-templates select="m:QueryMXCPISResponse/m:MXCPISSet" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="m:MXCPISSet">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>WP</th>
              <th>Site</th>
              <th>Shift</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="m:CPIS">
            ... etc.
```

Other info:

- Unless you are just transforming the payload in the SOAP body, you potentially need to do the same for the SOAP header `xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`
- If the target is Html, you should also set `<xsl:output method="html"/>` in the stylesheet.
- You can potentially DRY up your templates with further [apply-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342902/for-loops-vs-apply-templates), in preference to `xsl:for-each`