# concatenate element value if condition is satisfied in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

input xml -

```
       <Term payInNumberOfDays=\"30\">  
          <Ext  name=\"demo\">my</Ext>
        </Term>
        <Term payInNumberOfDays=\"0\">
          <Ext name=\"demo\">value</Ext>
        </Term>
        <Term payInNumberOfDays=\"0\">
          <Ext name=\"demo\">100</Ext>
        </Term>
```

I want to check `Ext @name="demo"`then concatenate all `Ext` element values with `-` in between

expected output  `<MYDC>my-value-100</MYDC>`

```
<xsl:variable name="var:v9">
                  <xsl:for-each select="Term">
                      <xsl:variable name="var:v30" select="userCSharp:LogicalEq(string(Ext/@name) , &quot;demo&quot;)" />
                      <xsl:if test="string($var:v30)='true'">
                          <xsl:if test="position() = 1"> <xsl:value-of select="Ext/text()" /> - </xsl:if>
                      </xsl:if>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:variable>
                <MYDC>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$var:v9" />
                </MYDC>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what the extension function is doing and why you need the variables but in plain XSLT 1.0 you could simply use

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Term/Ext[@name = 'demo']"/>
```

and then

```
  <xsl:template match="Ext">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">-</xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
```

see http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8m

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exsl msxml"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <MYDC>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Term/Ext[@name = 'demo']"/>
      </MYDC>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Ext">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">-</xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which transforms

```
<root>
        <Term payInNumberOfDays="30">  
          <Ext  name="demo">my</Ext>
        </Term>
        <Term payInNumberOfDays="0">
          <Ext name="demo">value</Ext>
        </Term>
        <Term payInNumberOfDays="0">
          <Ext name="demo">100</Ext>
        </Term>
</root>
```

into

```
<MYDC>my-value-100</MYDC>
```

Comment: can we have more simple answer ?

Comment: @Neo: *More simple?*  You must be kidding.  You've received a basic XSLT 1.0 answer that uses no extensions functions. The core answer is very simple, and it's supplemented with sample input, actual output, a demonstration link, and a leading summary that highlights the key part.  Your curt request for a *more simple answer* makes no sense.

Comment: @Neo: Ah, I may have figured out why you thought this answer wasn't simple.  See if reading [**For loops vs. appy-templates**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342902/for-loops-vs-apply-templates) doesn't help you past any aversion you have to using pattern matching and templates, which are better but can seem less simple to devs used to imperative programming.