# How to get right values from second XML file?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to take two separate XML files and with the use of XSL make them into one HTML file. I'm getting the right things from the first XML but when I'm trying the same from the second one, I either get all of the word in a single line or just the first one several times.

**XML** 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="xsltcss.css"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xslt.xsl" ?>    
<lexicon>
    <head>
        <title>Danish</title>
        <author>Mattias Liljegren</author>
    </head>
    <language value="danish">
        <word value="dog">hund</word>
        <word value="coffee">kaffe</word>
        <word value="tree">træ</word>
        <word value="chair">stol</word>
        <word value="flashlight">lommelygte</word>
        <word value="cat">kat</word>
        <word value="fish">fisk</word>
        <word value="car">bil</word>
        <word value="phone">telefon</word>
        <word value="forest">skov</word>
    </language>
</lexicon>
```

**XML** 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<lexicon>
    <head>
        <title>Croatian</title>
        <author>Mattias Liljegren</author>
    </head>
    <language value="croatian">
        <word value="dog">pas</word>
        <word value="coffee">kava</word>
        <word value="tree">drvo</word>
        <word value="chair">stolica</word>
        <word value="flashlight">baterija</word>
        <word value="cat">mačka</word>
        <word value="fish">riba</word>
        <word value="car">automobil</word>
        <word value="phone">telefon</word>
        <word value="forest">šuma</word>
    </language>
</lexicon>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xsltcss.css" />
         </head>
         <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="lexicon/head/title">
               <p>
                  <xsl:value-of select="." />
               </p>
               <p>
                  <xsl:value-of select="document('kroatiska.xml')/lexicon/head/title/." />
               </p>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="lexicon/language/word">
               <p>
                  <xsl:value-of select="." />
               </p>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="lexicon/language/word">
               <p>
                  <xsl:value-of select="document('kroatiska.xml')/lexicon/language/word" />
               </p>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Two separate xml files, I want the first word from each, then the second word and so on. Atm I'm getting the right ones from the original xml, but only the first word "pas" from the second xml file.

**Expected result:**

```
Danish
hund
kaffe 
trä  
stol  
lommelygte 
kat
fisk
bil
telefon 
skov
Croatian
pas 
kava
drvo
stolica
baterija
macka
riba
automobil
telefon
suma
```

Comment: What is the expected result of the transformation?

Comment: Also, are you really using an XSLT 2.0 processor? Your stylesheet says `version="2.0"` but this `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xslt.xsl" ?>` suggests you're doing the transformation in a browser, i.e. XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Atm I'm getting the top words as separate lines, and the bottom words as either the same amount of lines but only the first word pas, or all the words in a single line several times when i try to edit the code. I want it to take the first word from each xml, then the second word from each xml and so on. I dont know which processor I'm using tbh, doing this for school so I'm abit lost :)

Comment: I am afraid this is confusing. Please edit your question and add the exact result you expect to get from the given example. -- If you don't know which processor you're using, find out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033?r=SearchResults&s=1|27.1600#25245033

Comment: I've updated the bottom now so I hope its less confusing. I'm using version 1! edited it from 2.0 to 1, thanks!

Comment: I still don't see the expected result.

Comment: Updated again with window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought you would want to put the two lists side-by-side, as in a dictionary. To get the shown result of two separate lists is rather trivial:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/lexicon">
    <html>
        <body>
            <!-- this document -->
            <h3>
                <xsl:value-of select="language/@value"/>
            </h3>
            <xsl:for-each select="language/word">
                <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </p>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <!-- external document -->
            <xsl:variable name="kroatiska" select="document('kroatiska.xml')/lexicon" />
            <h3>
                <xsl:value-of select="$kroatiska/language/@value"/>
            </h3>
            <xsl:for-each select="$kroatiska//language/word">
                <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </p>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the engaging XSLT discussion [For loops vs. apply-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342902/for-loops-vs-apply-templates), consider an alternative version to avoid the the many `<xsl:for-each>` calls. As advised by XSLT gurus ([@Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343266/1422451), [@DimitreNovatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6344228/1422451), [@MichaelKay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6345067/1422451)):

- > Using `for-each` makes your program more complex by
  >   adding nesting levels and it's also impossibe to re-use the code
  >   inside the for-each block. Using `apply-templates` will (when done
  >   right) generates more flexible and modular XSLT.
- > Using `<xsl:template>` and `<xsl:apply-templates>` is much more powerful and elegant...`xsl:apply-templates` is much richer and deeper than `xsl:for-each`, even simply because we don't know what code will be applied on the nodes of the selection -- in the general case this code will be different for different nodes of the node-list.
- > The main benefits of `xsl:apply-templates` over `for-each` are that the code adapts better to changing document structures and changing processing requirements.

---

In your case, since you need to traverse the nodes in external document, `xsl:for-each`, is unavoidable:

**XSLT** *(using `lexicon`, `language`, and `word` templates)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="/lexicon">
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xsltcss.css" />
            </head>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="language" />
        </html>
   </xsl:template>   

   <xsl:template match="language">
        <body>
            <xsl:variable name="other_doc" select="document('kroatiska.xml')" />
            <h3>
               <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
            </h3>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="word" />
            <h3>
                <xsl:value-of select="$other_doc/lexicon/language/@value" />
            </h3>
            <xsl:for-each select="$other_doc/lexicon/language/word">
                <p>
                  <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
                </p>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
   </xsl:template>   

   <xsl:template match="word">
        <p>
          <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
        </p>
   </xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xsltcss.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>danish</h3>
    <p>hund</p>
    <p>kaffe</p>
    <p>træ</p>
    <p>stol</p>
    <p>lommelygte</p>
    <p>kat</p>
    <p>fisk</p>
    <p>bil</p>
    <p>telefon</p>
    <p>skov</p>
    <h3>croatian</h3>
    <p>pas</p>
    <p>kava</p>
    <p>drvo</p>
    <p>stolica</p>
    <p>baterija</p>
    <p>mačka</p>
    <p>riba</p>
    <p>automobil</p>
    <p>telefon</p>
    <p>šuma</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you think that *"since you need to traverse the nodes in external document, `xsl:for-each`, is unavoidable"*? -- P.S. I believe using `xsl:for-each` is a better choice in this case: it makes the code shorter and more readable. Your version, IMHO, suffers from the GOTO syndrome.

Comment: If you can show how to avoid the `xsl:for-each` on nodes via `document()`, I am very interested! Maybe in 2.0? Also, OP may have a much larger XML with other nodes and only posted a snippet here. Plus, future, novice XSLT readers may believe multiple `for-each` from root is the only way. Again, this is an alternative approach, hopefully citing a general best practice.

Comment: I have posted another answer showing that. -- There is no "general best practice". Each case needs to be weighed on its own.

Answer (score 0):

This is an expansion of the comments following the answer by Parfait.

In his answer, Parfait says:

> In your case, since you need to traverse the nodes in external document, `xsl:for-each`, is unavoidable:

In a comment I asked why would that be, and Parfait replied:

> If you can show how to avoid the `xsl:for-each` on nodes via `document()`, I am very interested!

The following stylesheet shows how to get the same result using only `apply-templates`:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/lexicon">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="language | document('kroatiska.xml')/lexicon/language" />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="language">
    <h3>
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </h3>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="word">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

This is not meant to imply that using `xsl:apply-templates` is somehow better in this case than `xsl:for-each`.