# How to handle '<BR/>' element and convert string in new paragraph

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xquery

In the below example we are trying to handle 'BR' element under the 'P' element and convert into the seprate paragraph using 'XSLT 1.0':

Can anyone help.

**INPUT XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CONTENT>
<P>A. 05° 55’ 47.81” S – 106° 32’ 10.76” E<BR/>B. 05° 55’ 47.81” S – 106° 34’ 10.76” E<BR/>C. 05° 55’ 47.81” S – 106° 36’ 10.76” E<BR/>D. 05° 57’ 47.81” S – 106° 32’ 10.76” E<BR/>E. 05° 57’ 47.81’’S – 106° 34’ 10.76’’E<BR/>F. 05° 57’ 47.81’’S – 106° 36’ 10.76’’E<BR/>G. 05° 59’ 47.81’’S – 106° 32’ 10.76’’E<BR/>H. 05° 59’ 47.81’’S – 106° 34’ 10.76’’E<BR/>I. 05° 59’ 47.81’’S – 106° 36’ 10.76’’E</P>
</CONTENT>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CONTENT>
<P>A. 05° 55’ 47.81” S – 106° 32’ 10.76” E</P>
<P>B. 05° 55’ 47.81” S – 106° 34’ 10.76” E</P>
<P>C. 05° 55’ 47.81” S – 106° 36’ 10.76” E</P>
<P>D. 05° 57’ 47.81” S – 106° 32’ 10.76” E</P>
<P>E. 05° 57’ 47.81’’S – 106° 34’ 10.76’’E</P>
<P>F. 05° 57’ 47.81’’S – 106° 36’ 10.76’’E</P>
<P>G. 05° 59’ 47.81’’S – 106° 32’ 10.76’’E</P>
<P>H. 05° 59’ 47.81’’S – 106° 34’ 10.76’’E</P>
<P>I. 05° 59’ 47.81’’S – 106° 36’ 10.76’’E</P>
</CONTENT>
```

**XSLT CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Reference Link:** https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEJbVso/1

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  >
  
  <xsl:template match="P[BR]">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="BR[1]/preceding-sibling::text()"/></p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="BR"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="P/BR[following-sibling::BR]">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::BR[1]/preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()]"/></p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="P/BR[not(following-sibling::BR)]">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::text()"/></p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Compared with [michael.hor257k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67054121/4453460), this one has three templates that are _almost, but not exactly, identical_: in a longish stylesheet that sometimes needs to be updated they could be difficult to maintain (typical situation: you remember to fix one or two, and forget the others).

Comment: His answer is the easiest to understand and maybe the easiest to maintain...depending if other inline-elements are introduces. 
My xslt will also create empty p if there are two br with no text in between and if after the last br there is no text-node.

Answer (score 2):

> we are trying to handle 'BR' element under the 'P' element and convert into the seprate paragraph

Actually, you do **not** need to handle the `BR` elements at all.

All you need to do is address the **individual text nodes** (already separated by the `BR` element) and convert each one of these into a separate `P` element:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/CONTENT">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="P/text()">
            <P>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </P>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why do you need the tag `<xsl:copy>`?

Comment: @PierreFrançois To create the root `CONTENT` element. -- P.S. It's an *instruction*, not a *tag*.

Comment: Very good answer. But why use for-each. I have learned to  use apply templates as much as possible.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342902/for-loops-vs-apply-templates