# Display empty XML data node as text message

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am fairly new to xml and I'm having a weird problem with templates.  For empty data nodes, instead of displaying a blank space where the data should be, I want to display a message like 'None Found' or 'No Data' on an html page.  I have done both an xsl:choose statement and 2 xsl:if statements with no success.  I already know this particular node is empty, I just want to show a message instead of a blank space.  The Otherwise or False statements just don't seem to run at all.  Please help!!  What am I doing wrong here?

**The XML Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
<findings>
    <ssns/>
    <dobs>
     <dob>
         <data>082967</data>
     </dob>   
    </dobs> 
    <dobs>
        <dob>
         <data>020568</data>
        </dob>
    </dobs>
 
    <names>
        <name>
        <full>Homer J Simpson</full>
        <first>Homer</first>
        <last>Simpson</last>
        <middle>J</middle>
        </name>
    </names>
    <names>
        <name>
        <full>Marge H Simpson</full>
        <first>Marge</first>
        <last>Simpson</last>
        <middle>H</middle>
        </name>
    </names>
</findings>
</Root>
```

**The XSL Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>Person Results</title>
        </head>
        
        <div style="font-weight:bold">Alias(es):</div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Root/findings/names"/>
        
        <div style="font-weight:bold">SSNs:</div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Root/findings/ssns"/>
        
        <div style="font-weight:bold">DOBs:</div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Root/findings/dobs"/>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

    
    <xsl:template match="Root/findings/names">
      <p>
      <xsl:variable name="nmesHasData" select="boolean(normalize-space(name))"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="name">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$nmesHasData">
            <ul> <xsl:apply-templates select="full"/> </ul>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>None found</xsl:text>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </p>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Root/findings/ssns">
      <p>
        <xsl:variable name="ssnHasData" select="boolean(normalize-space(ssns))"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="ssn">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$ssnHasData">
           <ul><xsl:apply-templates select="data"/></ul>
         </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>None found</xsl:text>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </p>
  
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Root/findings/dobs">
      <p>
        <xsl:variable name="dobHasData" select="boolean(normalize-space(dob))"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="dob">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$dobHasData">
           <ul><xsl:apply-templates select="data"/></ul>
         </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>None found</xsl:text>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </p>
  
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:transform>
```

**The HTML Result**

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "XSLT-compat">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Person Results</title>
   </head>
   <div style="font-weight:bold">Alias(es):</div>
   <p>
      <ul>Homer J Simpson</ul>
   </p>
   <p>
      <ul>Marge H Simpson</ul>
   </p>
   <div style="font-weight:bold">SSNs:</div>
   <p></p>
   <div style="font-weight:bold">DOBs:</div>
   <p>
      <ul>082967</ul>
   </p>
   <p>
      <ul>020568</ul>
   </p>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add 2 examples of XML input: one that qualifies as  "empty" and one that does not - see: [mcve].

Comment: Change $dobHasData = 'true' to $dobHasData = true()

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed What difference would that make?

Comment: Which version of XSLT do you use? Can a `dobs` element have several `dob` child elements? Do you want to process/check each of them separately?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I have modified my submission to show a fuller picture of my code.  I guess I'm referring to the template correctly, right?  I have a feeling that my issue has to do with my trying to display text outside of the HTML block...?

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed, thanks for the suggestion, but that did not make a difference, I'm still getting blank results and no text message.

Comment: I don’t see any dobs element in your xml, although you are using it in the match where you are testing the empty dob?

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed, sorry I left off the 's' from DOB in my code.  DOB is short for Date of Birth, which in this case, the node is empty.  I'm just trying to display a text message when there is nothing in the node.

Comment: Be more precise in your sample xsl and source xsl. The xml was not well-formed and there was a mismatch between the xml-element Root and xsl-xpath root. Now we have to guess what you want. I hope my guessing was correct :-)

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed, I have modified my sample xml and source xsl to be more clear.  The main problem I'm having is that I just want to display "nothing found" for an empty node.  In my modified code above, the empty node is now "<ssns/>".  However the 'None found' text never displays even though it has no data.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the template match="Root/findings/dobs" to this:

```
  <xsl:template match="Root/findings/dobs">
    <p>
      <xsl:for-each select="dob">
        <xsl:variable name="dobHasData" select="boolean(normalize-space(.))"/>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$dobHasData">
            <ul><xsl:apply-templates select="data"/></ul>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>None found</xsl:text>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </p>
    
  </xsl:template>
```

Or even [more template matching like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342902/for-loops-vs-apply-templates):

```
  <xsl:template match="Root/findings/dobs">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="dob"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="dob">
      <xsl:variable name="dobHasData" select="boolean(normalize-space(.))"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$dobHasData">
          <ul><xsl:apply-templates select="data"/></ul>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:text>None found</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

And this last template could also be splitted in two short ones:

```
  <xsl:template match="dob[normalize-space(.)]">
    <ul><xsl:apply-templates select="data"/></ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dob[not(normalize-space(.))]">
    <xsl:text>None found</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Siebe, for some reason, only the split templates worked for me, but I have a solution now anyway.  Thanks again.