XSLT TRANSFORM, taking values after checking and going back to root node
I have below XML. I need to loop into the node ExamStatus\E_Status and see if the status is "Rejected" then have to go to the node <Exam_Center> and extract Centername and centerno, along with other node elements in the top nodes and create a new XML. This will repeat and there are more than 200k lines. I was thinking about foreach loop but it is not giving any output and seems like there is some approach of traverse back to root.
<ExamDetails>
    <Ex_Descripiton>
        <ExamMethod>writing</ExamMethod>
        <OnPaper>Green</OnPaper>
    </Ex_Descripiton>
    <ExamInfo>
        <Grade>11TH</Grade>
        <Grade-Tsk>I</Grade-Tsk>
        <Desc>txt11,txt12,txt13</Desc>
        <University>Cacllc</University>
        <Exv1 Segment="1">
            <HIGHESTMark>100</HIGHESTMark>
            <LowestMark>40</LowestMark>
        </Exv1>
        <Exv2 Segment="2">
            <HIGHESTMark>100</HIGHESTMark>
            <LowestMark>40</LowestMark>
        </Exv2>
        <Exam_Center Segment="1">
            <CenterName>calicut</CenterName>
            <CenterNo>289</CenterNo>
            <CeterGroup>1</CeterGroup>
        </Exam_Center>
        <ExamModel_Item  segment="1">
            <MODEL_ID>15 </MODEL_ID>
            <MODEL_Name>physic</MODEL_Name>
            <MODEL_DATE>07-23-2024</MODEL_DATE>
        </ExamModel_Item>
        <ExamModel_Partners  segment="2">
            <Colleges>40</Colleges>
            <MODEL_Name>Social</MODEL_Name>
            <MODEL_DATE>07-23-2024</MODEL_DATE>
        </ExamModel_Partners>
        <ExamModel_Partners  segment="2">
            <Colleges>45</Colleges>
            <MODEL_Name>maths</MODEL_Name>
            <MODEL_DATE>07-23-2024</MODEL_DATE>
        </ExamModel_Partners>
        <ExamStatus Segment="1">
            <E_Name>Maths</E_Name>
            <E_Date>07-23-2024</E_Date>
            <E_Status>Completed</E_Status>
        </ExamStatus>
        <ExamStatus Segment="1">
            <E_Name>physic</E_Name>
            <E_Date>07-23-2024</E_Date>
            <E_Status>Rejected</E_Status>
        </ExamStatus>
        <ExamStatus Segment="1">
            <E_Name>Social</E_Name>
            <E_Date>07-23-2024</E_Date>
            <E_Status>Completed</E_Status>
        </ExamStatus>
    </ExamInfo>
    <ExamInfo>
        <Grade>12TH</Grade>
        <Grade-Tsk>I</Grade-Tsk>
        <Desc>txt11,txt12,txt13</Desc>
        <University>Delhi</University>
        <Exv1 Segment="1">
            <HIGHESTMark>100</HIGHESTMark>
            <LowestMark>40</LowestMark>
        </Exv1>
        <Exv2 Segment="2">
            <HIGHESTMark>100</HIGHESTMark>
            <LowestMark>40</LowestMark>
        </Exv2>
        <Exam_Center Segment="1">
            <CenterName>Mumbai</CenterName>
            <CenterNo>300</CenterNo>
            <CeterGroup>1</CeterGroup>
        </Exam_Center>
        <ExamModel_Item  segment="1">
            <MODEL_ID>15 </MODEL_ID>
            <MODEL_Name>physic</MODEL_Name>
            <MODEL_DATE>07-23-2024</MODEL_DATE>
        </ExamModel_Item>
        <ExamModel_Partners  segment="2">
            <Colleges>40</Colleges>
            <MODEL_Name>Social</MODEL_Name>
            <MODEL_DATE>07-23-2024</MODEL_DATE>
        </ExamModel_Partners>
        <ExamModel_Partners  segment="2">
            <Colleges>45</Colleges>
            <MODEL_Name>maths</MODEL_Name>
            <MODEL_DATE>07-23-2024</MODEL_DATE>
        </ExamModel_Partners>
        <ExamStatus Segment="1">
            <E_Name>Maths</E_Name>
            <E_Date>07-23-2024</E_Date>
            <E_Status>Completed</E_Status>
        </ExamStatus>
        <ExamStatus Segment="1">
            <E_Name>physic</E_Name>
            <E_Date>07-23-2024</E_Date>
            <E_Status>Rejected</E_Status>
        </ExamStatus>
    </ExamInfo>
</ExamDetails>

The code which i am trying is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/ExamInfo"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/ExamInfo/ExamStatus">
        <xsl:for-each select="/ExamInfo/ExamStatus">
            <!-- <CenterName><xsl:value-of select="'this is test'"/></CenterName> -->
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="/E_Status='Rejected'">
                    <CenterName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="/ExamDetails/Exam_Center/CenterName"/>
                    </CenterName>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>


Please edit your question and add the expected result.

your for-each assumes that there are ExamInfo/ExamStatus under the ExamInfo/ExamStatus that the template matches, which is not the case, why do you think you want the for-each?

You haven't given a clear description or an example of the output you want, and your XSLT code has errors which make it hard to see what you're trying to do, so it's hard to suggest a solution. Please explain clearly what you want to output, e.g. "a list of the ExamInfo elements (but only those which have at least one 'Rejected' ExamStatus), and with some child elements removed", and provide an example.

One substantive criticism is that your XPath expressions all begin with / which makes them "absolute" paths starting at the root of the document. e.g. <xsl:when test="/E_Status='Rejected'"> is a test that the root element is <E_Status>Rejected</E_Status>, which is clearly not what you want. Lose the initial / on those XPath expressions which are intended to be evaluated relative to the context node, and you will have made some real progress. I hope this will help you: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#location-paths

You are thinking about this very procedurally: "after checking", "I need to loop", "and then go back", "this will repeat". Try to describe the required output as a function of the input, rather than describing a sequence of steps to be followed.

The most obvious error in your code is excessive use of a leading "/". You need to read up about how "context" works in XSLT, how instructions change the context node and how path expressions select from the context node.

While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML with all relevant namespaces.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Hello thanks for the input. I have a doubt. As the  <Exam_Center Segment="1"> is a node inside the root , you had applied the condition  <xsl:variable name="center" select="Exam_Center" />.  But if i need to go one more step inside the exam center like  <Exam_Center Segment="1">INDIAMH
<Center_Details>
300
Mumbai
</Center_Details>
</Exam_Center>
Here i need to take CenterNo and also Location, then how can achieve ?

You could probably do something like:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ExamDetails">
    <results>
        <xsl:for-each select="ExamInfo/ExamStatus[E_Status='Rejected']">
            <Exam>
                <ExamName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="E_Name"/>
                </ExamName>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../Exam_Center/CenterName"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../Exam_Center/CenterNo"/>
            </Exam>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </results>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

But since you need to extract more than one item from the Exam_Center and esp. since you say the input document is large, you might want to do it more efficiently:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ExamDetails">
    <results>
        <xsl:for-each select="ExamInfo">
            <xsl:variable name="center" select="Exam_Center" />
            <xsl:for-each select="ExamStatus[E_Status='Rejected']">
                <Exam>
                    <ExamName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="E_Name"/>
                    </ExamName>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$center/CenterName | $center/CenterNo"/>
                </Exam>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </results>
</xsl:template>
   
</xsl:stylesheet>


You may be able to avoid for-each by using apply-templates and axes operators: XSLT Fiddle.

@Parfait I do not want to avoid xsl:for-each.

See this answer and other answers on why avoid it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6345067/3710053

@SiebeJongebloed A recommendation to learn other methods (which I support) is not a reason to avoid using xsl:for-each where appropriate (as it is here).

Hello thanks for the input. I have a doubt. As the  <Exam_Center Segment="1"> is a node inside the root , you had applied the condition  <xsl:variable name="center" select="Exam_Center" />.

Hello  2 thanks for the input. I have a doubt. As the  <Exam_Center Segment="1"> is a node inside the root , you had applied the condition  <xsl:variable name="center" select="Exam_Center" />.  But if i need to go one more step inside the exam center like  <Exam_Center Segment="1">INDIAMH
<Center_Details>
300
Mumbai
</Center_Details>
</Exam_Center>
Here i need to take CenterNo and also Location, then how can achieve ?

<xsl:copy-of select="$center/CenterNo | $center/Location"/>

Thanks for the guidance, getting into :)
